# Using streams/collect to generate a map in Java 8

Tags: java-8

I'm playing around with maps/streams in Java 8 and I don't see a straightforward way to convert the following Java 7 code.  It seems as though I cannot access a method within a method.  If I use a .map() as an intermediate step, I lose access to the outer variable("item").  Am I missing something?

```
private void test(final Collection<SomeObject> items){
    // Java 7
    Map<SomeKey, List<SomeObject>> map = Maps.newHashMap();
    for (SomeObject item : items){
        SomeKey someKey = item.someMethod().getKey(); 
        map.put(someKey,item);
    }
    // Java 8
    Map<SomeKey, List<SomeObject>> map2 = 
      items.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(item::someMethod::getKey));
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I don't see any problematic mapping step. Just replace the malformed method reference `item::someMethod::getKey` with a correct lambda expression `item -> item.someMethod().getKey()`

Comment: @Holger I've added an answer with your comment, but feel free to come back and add it and I will upvote it!

Answer (score 0):

The correct Java 8 expression should be:

```
Map<SomeKey, List<SomeObject>> map2 = 
      items.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(item -> item.someMethod().getKey()));
```